# Spring WS + JAXB Testing

Tags: junit4, spring-ws

I'm trying to write junit test for simple Enpoint web service:

```
@Endpoint
public class TestWS {

  @PayloadRoot(localPart = "GetAllPlayersRequest", namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
  public @ResponsePayload GetAllPlayersResponse handleGetAllPlayersRequest() {
        ...
  }
}
```

My test looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:**/tb-ws-servlet.xml" })
public class TeambridgeWSTest extends AbstractWebServiceServerTest {

  private MockWebServiceClient client;

  @Autowired
  public void setApplicationContex(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      client = createClient(applicationContext);
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldReturnAllPlayers() throws Exception {
      ParametrizableRequestCreator message = withMessage("GetAllPlayersRequest.xml");
      client.sendRequest(message).andExpect(message("messages="GetAllPlayersResponse.xml"));
  }

}
```

and GetAllPlayersRequest.xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://ws.tb.company.com/schemas">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sch:GetAllPlayersRequest/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have no idea why I get

```
No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage  http://ws.tb.company.com/schemas}GetAllPlayersRequest]
```

I'm experienced in Spring, but still new in Spring WS. Do you have any suggestions to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of NAMESPACE_URI? I suppose it's:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://ws.tb.company.com/schemas";
```

You've also configured your Spring web service XML file using annotation driven, haven't you?

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.here"/>

<sws:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: For both questions the answer is yes